# Cast a circle around an object and detect other objects in range (with visual)

Tags: 2d, unity

I have my "player" object moving around an arena type area, with miscellaneous objects scattered about. What I want to do is move the player near any of these objects, and on keypress I want to display a circular radius with the player in the center that will detect nearby objects (eventually being filtered by tag).

I realize there are many ways to accomplish this, but being relatively new to Unity I am trying to find a way that is intuitive to me. Looking at the documentation, Physics2D.CircleCastAll seems like it would fit my needs, but I am unable to test at this time (at work).

Provided CircleCastAll is what I do use, is there a way in the scene to display the circle that is being cast so that the player can visually see the radius? I know it returns a RayCastHit2D, so I can get the objects from that, but the player should have something visual to let them know if they are slightly out of range or not.

Any suggesions/tips are welcome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your rendered effect is going to be completely separated from the physics cast.  The cast will tell you *what* is there, you will need to handle the drawing with a separate object.  Decals are frequently used.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are misunderstanding how `CircleCastAll` works. A good analogy to describe it is that `CircleCastAll` is throwing a frisbee of a certain radius over a distance and then returning all object that this frisbee hits. What I think you are looking for is a circle that emanates from the user and that does not move over a distance. The proper way to perform this action is with [`OverlapCircleAll`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll.html). For this you would simply set the `point` of the circle to be your player's position and the `radius` to the radius of your desired circle.

Now onto the hard part. `OverlapCircleAll` and all other Physics functions in only return the Colliders of **the things that were hit**. They do not interact with visuals in any way. This you will need to do on your own. The easiest way I can think of to do this is to have an animated circle appear that is the same radius as your `OverlapCircleAll` appear at the same time as your `OverlapCircleAll`.

Comment: This helped me out a lot. OverlapCircleAll makes way more sense then CircleCastAll for my needs, thanks for that help!